# Powershell not working to disable Windows Update

Tags: windows-10, powershell, windows-update

I have been using the command: sc.exe config wuauserv start=disabled on Powershell to disable Windows Updates in Windows 10. But I am unable to do so today after recent Windows Update.

This is the message I am getting using above sc.exe command.
[SC] OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.

Please suggest how can i fix this.

Comment: yes powershell is in administrator mode.

Comment: My batch script for cmd prompt still works on 1809 and latest updates.

Answer (score 0):

Please be sure to spend the time to get spun up on PowerShell using all the no cost online training (YouTube, Microsoft Virtual Academy, MS Channel9, etc.) and no cost [eBooks](https://leanpub.com/u/devopscollective), and the pick up some of the highly recommended PS books via Amazon.

As for what you are doing, this is not the way to run external exe in the PS console host or ISE or VSCode.

Exe's run in cmd.exe not in PS. Calling and exe in PS needs shell to cmd.exe, but you have to do that in code.

[PowerShell has special characters that are reserved.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_special_characters?view=powershell-6) The '=' is an assignment operator, so that straight cmd.exe like command cannot be used directly. How to run exe via PS is fully documented.

[PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx)

[PowerShell - Special Characters And Tokens](http://www.neolisk.com/techblog/powershell-specialcharactersandtokens)

There are several different methods for running executables as well as invoking code. How do you know which one to use for the job? Here is an outline of the methods with examples and general use.

```
# Your - sc.exe config wuauserv start=disabled
# becomes like this...
# Start and external process calling sc.exe and pass the arguments to SC.exe
Start-Process -FilePath sc.exe -ArgumentList 'config wuauserv start=disabled'
```